# PHP If/Else Statements

Tags: php, mysql, logging

I have a mysql table called `users` with the following fields:

```
username - password - role
```

The role consists of normal user and admin.

What I want is so when an admin logs in it gets redirected to another page and not the same page a normal user would log in. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
include("../includes/db.php");

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' And role = 'normaluser'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
session_register("username");
session_register("password");
header("location:myaccount.php");
}
?>
```

I have the code working for the normal user but I just don't know how to write the code for the admin part.

Comment: You can probably add an extra column to your database. say "admin" and next to those users that are admin, make them a value of 1. so you can check if admin = 1, then header(...)

Comment: I'm wondering what the purpose of your `session_register` calls is, since you're not actually registering any values.

Comment: @andrewliu I believe that's the purpose of the role column that OP describes.

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say

```
$sql="SELECT role FROM Users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    //one hit i hope?!
    //DONT save your apssword in the session!!!!
    //session_register("username");
    //session_register("password");

    $role = $row->role;

}
if($role == "user"){
    redirect1
}elseif($role == "admin"){
   redirect2;
}else{
  redirect panic
}
```

Comment: +1 for not storing the password. To further expand on this, don't save plain text passwords, either.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right ofcourse, but to keep the answer close enough to the question I skipped that. But as @metalfrog said: look into storing non-plain passwords :)

Answer (score 2):

Retrieve `role` from the query, check to see what it is, then set the header location accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
// ...
if($count == 1){
   $user = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   if ($user['role'] === 'normaluser')
   {
      session_register("username");
      session_register("password");
      header("location:myaccount.php");
   }
   if ($user['role'] === 'admin')
   {
      header("location:admin.php");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define some constants like below or use the bitmasking algoritim. (php_manual).

**index.php** or if your using a framework check the docs.

```
define('USER_ADMIN', 'a');
define('USER_USER', 'u');
```

**build a permissions table with type text set to null**

```
`permissions` text null
```

**to build your user_permissions row in your views use the checkbox's**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="u" selected />
<input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="a" selected />
```

**assigning data**

```
$user='';

$user = (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) ? User::find($_SESSION['uid']) : '';



if(isset($user) && in_array(USER_ADMIN, $user['permissions']))
{
   //i am an admin
}
else
{
  //i am NOT an admin
}
```